# Excel application freezes while initializing object using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: excel, office-interop, citrix

I used dll Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel version 15.0.0.0
and created object as below

```
Application excelApp = new Application();
```

Execution hangs in above line.

I have released COM objects in finally block as below

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelApp);
```

It is WPF Application which is published on citrix. It was working when citrix server was running in windows 2008. But later it was upgraded to windows 2016.
The excel freeze issue in above line of code is intermittent. It works for few users and doesn't work for others.

May I know how to fix the issue.

I checked event viewer and it gives DistributedCOM error, not exactly as soon as creating excel object. I have attached picture of event viewer.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6oZG.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use the `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject` method, instead use the `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` one where possible.

And here is what Microsoft states for that:

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

> If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.

You may consider using the [Open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) if you deal with open XML documents only. Otherwise, you may consider using components designed for the ser-side execution.

Comment: I tried that but didn't work. I checked event viewer and it gives DistributedCOM error. Not exactly as soon as creating excel object. I have attached picture of event viewer.

Comment: That's what [Microsoft states for the issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2). Use the Open XML SDK or third party components designed for the server-side execution.

Comment: But excel opens sometimes when exported from our app that is published on citrix. Most of the times it freezes.   Why is it intermittent ?
The issue should have been for all users, but thats not the case. There are many citrix servers where users will be running our app, for few of them it works and for few it doesn't

Comment: The question says "It is WPF Application which is published on citrix". Not an "unattended, non-interactive client application or component". So that quote from Microsoft doesn't seem relevant?